# How to convert datetime to hex code in java?

Tags: java

I need to convert date time into hex code and store it in byte `array.length` of the hex code should be 17 or 18, because i need to store it in
byte array of [9].

Following is the format which i am looking for.

```
EXAMPLE: Thursday 17:35:20 December 15, 2005 is encoded as
07D50C0F112314FFFF.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us the tried code

Comment: i dont have any thats the problem. actually i tried different. method but the length is more than i need. i tried date to string and then string to hex but it is problem when i convert it hex to date.

Comment: why don't you use: date => unix timestamp => hex?

Comment: @RC can u please share code for same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using: date => unix timestamp => hex:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Dates {
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 15);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2005);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 17);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 35);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
        final Date date = cal.getTime();

        System.out.printf("Date %s is encoded as: %s\n", date, Long.toHexString(date.getTime()));
        // decode with: new Date(Long.parseLong("1082f469308", 16))
    }
}
```

Output:

> Date Thu Dec 15 17:35:20 CET 2005 is encoded as: 1082f469308

Comment: Shall we give codes to those who even do not attempt to try on their own

Comment: hello RC Thanks for the code it works fine but, length is 11 of hex string. i need 17 or 18.

Comment: @javaBeginner U seems like my class teacher. Believe me sir i tried by myself n then asked question. You are good though. Thanks anyway for drawing ur attention in this thread and not helping me out.

Comment: @Rahul I am just following *how to ask* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask .Please read this and let me know if i am wrong in my previuos comment

Comment: @javaBeginner no hard feelings.  but i am in hurry. so asking for code instead. will try to follow manual next time. sorry and thanks.

Comment: need Hex in 8 digits just like  date and time in hex is 47C7EDE0 for this date 12:34:56 29/Feb/2008
Please help

Comment: @Harneet this question and answer are from 2013.. Please [create a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you need it.

Comment: Posted new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45136264/how-to-convert-date-time-in-hex-in-android