# How to convert date time in hex in android

Tags: java, android, hex, iot

I need to convert date and time in hex code for writing it on IOT device. 
Here is my code

```
private String getDateTimeToHexa() { 

Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone gmtTime =  TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());

    mCalendar.setTimeZone(gmtTime);
    final Date date = mCalendar.getTime();
    return Long.toHexString(date.getTime());
}
```

It is returning 11 digits hex code I need 8 digits, just like date and time in hex is `47C7EDE0` for this date `12:34:56 29/Feb/2008`

Please help

Comment: `Integer.toHexString((int)(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000))`?

Comment: Value returned by `date.getTime()` is in milliseconds, but the hex value `47C7EDE0` is in seconds. That's why comment by @shmosel is correct, because it converts the milliseconds to seconds, before converting that to hex. To see that `47C7EDE0` is in seconds, try printing `new Date(0x47C7EDE0 * 1000L)`. I get `Fri Feb 29 06:34:56 EST 2008` because I'm in Eastern US time zone.

Comment: If you have Java 8, print `Instant.ofEpochSecond(0x47C7EDE0)` and you get `2008-02-29T11:34:56Z`. The date you show seems to be in Central European time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 private String getDateTimeToHexa() {
        Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        TimeZone gmtTime =  TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());
        mCalendar.setTimeZone(gmtTime);
        final Date date = mCalendar.getTime();
        return Long.toHexString(date.getTime()/1000);
    }
```

Comment: One does not simply cast a millisecond timestamp to `int`.

Comment: Of course not. You're just truncating data without any conversion logic.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
public class Date {
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 15);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2005);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 17);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 35);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
    final Date date = cal.getTime();

    System.out.printf("Date %s is encoded as: %s\n", date, Long.toHexString(date.getTime()));
    // decode with: new Date(Long.parseLong("1082f469308", 16))
}
```

}

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning

```
return Long.toHexString(date.getTime());
```

Return following

```
return Long.toHexString(date.getTime()/1000);
```

As correctly pointed out by @shmosel that date.getTime() return time in a millisecond and if you want 8 digit Hex format then it needs to be converted in the second format.

The return type of Date can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime())